# Database design for chat room. Need to save every chat

Tags: mysql, database-design

*Scenario:* 
Designing a chat room for various users to chat at a time. All the chats needs to saved. Whenever user logs in, he should be able to see all the previous chats.

Here is one example of the table that can be used for storing the chats:

```
CREATE TABLE chat 
(
  chat_id int NOT NULL auto_increment,
  posted_on datetime NOT NULL,
  userid int NOT NULL,
  message text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (chat_id),
  FOREIGN KEY(userid) references users(userid) on update cascade on delete cascade
);
```

For retrieving chats in proper order, I need some primary key in the table in which I am storing the chats. So, if I use the above table for storing chats then I cannot store more than 2147483647 chats. Obviously, I can use some datatype which has huge range like unsigned bigint, but still it will have some limit.

But as the scenario says that the chats to be saved can be infinite, so what kind of table should I make? Should I make some other primary key?

Please help me sorting out the solution. I wonder how Google or facebook manage to save every chat.

Comment: What's wrong with bigint?  That gives you range up to 9223372036854775807 unique instances.  If you have 1 billion chats a day, then it will take 9 billion years before you exceed that range.

Comment: But i think having a big table is a perforance drawback.

Comment: @selbie Someone told me when table becomes too big, just dump the data of the table into a file, and empty the table and when that data is required just load the data from the file to the table. And this is how Google or fb saves infinite data. But I dont know if this is the correct soln or if it is correct then how exactly to implement it.

Comment: A table with an index column that is 64-bit will not be performance hit. Having a table with more than a billion rows might be a perf hit!

Comment: One other suggestion.  Google and Facebook didn't have the scalability they did on their first day of their first release. Over time, both companies invested in massive storage solutions and distributed computing and adapted their code and features to the evolving backend.  Unless you already got their data center at your disposal, I would start off with a standard set of relational tables that seperate out "messages", "chats", and "users". Where "message" is {userid, text, date/time, chatid} and "chats" are {chatid, starttime, endtime} and possibly some support for users coming and going.

Comment: Why do you need a "primary key"? Is a chat message really uniquely identified by their time, and not the "chat_id" column, for instance? Can you really guarantee that no two users will ever send a message at exactly the same time? Do you not just need an index?

Comment: If you use a timestamp accurate to milliseconds combined with the user ID, that should be "unique enough."  It's unlikely that a legitimate user would send multiple messages in the same millisecond.  Maybe some sort of bot or system service might, however.  Any reason this has to be a database and not a text log?

Answer (score 0):

If you weren't using MySQL, a primary key of the user id and a timestamp would probably work fine. But MySQL's timestamp only resolves to one second. (See below for recent changes that affect this answer.)  There are a few ways to get around that.

- Let application code handle a primary key violation by waiting a
  second, then resubmitting.
- Let application code provide a higher-precision timestamp, and store
  it as a sortable CHAR(n), like '2011-01-01 03:45:46.987'.
- Switch to a dbms that supports microsecond timestamps.

All that application code needs to be server-side code if you intend to write a query that presents rows ordered by timestamp.

**Later**

The current version of MySQL supports [fractional seconds in timestamps](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fractional-seconds.html).

Comment: MariaDB 5.3 (still in beta) is supporting microseconds in datetime and timestamp types: http://kb.askmonty.org/en/microseconds-in-mariadb

Comment: Starting the key with a non sequential value such as a userid would cause data to be inserted randomly into the table at different points. It's best to sequentially add new data to the end of the table. Especially helps with indexes.